# Swift download file from ftp server and encode it from utf 16 (xml file)

Tags: xml, swift, encoding, ftp

Hello I need to download a xml file from ftp server with swift.
The download works and I tried it out with a xml file which is encoded in utf8. 
But if I download the file that I need which has a utf 16 encoding I got a big byte array with many 0 bytes. 
When I try to encode and save it. It saves a file which is much biger as the original file. 
I already tried to remove the 0 bytes and encode and save it like this.
The result is that the encoding doesn't work and I get something like that

!!!!!Result: Optional(䐼瑡湥ਾ㰉敚汩㹥ऊ㰉敚汩湥慢捲摯㹥䉚ぃ〰〰〰㤷⼼敚汩湥慢捲摯㹥ऊ㰉牐橯步湴浵敭㹲ㄱ㄰〲㄰〰⼼牐橯步湴浵敭㹲ऊ㰉牐橯步扴獥档敲扩湵㹧䉅⁚䅄⁇剂〲‵㉚䄭晵慢汵湩敩⁮䱐䠠湵㱤倯潲敪瑫敢捳牨楥畢杮ਾउ䈼獥档敲扩湵㹧䐲䐠瑥楡㱬䈯獥档敲扩

This is how I encode the byte array

```
   let result = NSString(bytes: bytes, length: bufferSize, encoding: encoding)
    println("!!!Groesse: \(bufferSize) \n")
    println("!!!!!Result: \(result)")

    if result != nil
    {
        return result!
    }
    else
    {
        return ""
    }
```

My buffersize is 9999999 at the moment and the original file size is 148440.
And this is the download function

```
 let ftpReadStream = self.createFTPReadStream(fileName)
    CFReadStreamOpen(ftpReadStream)

    var numBytesRead = 0
    var buffer = [UInt8](count: bufferSize, repeatedValue: 0)

    do
    {
        //TODO: Buffer überlauf?
        numBytesRead =  CFReadStreamRead(ftpReadStream, &buffer, bufferSize)
    }
    while( numBytesRead > 0 );

    CFReadStreamClose(ftpReadStream)
    /*var data = NSData(bytes: buffer, length: bufferSize)
    data.writeToFile("/Users/nilskunkel/KirchnerTimeDaten/XMLs/Test.xml", options: NSDataWritingOptions.DataWritingAtomic, error: nil)*/
    var data = self.removePadding(buffer)

    self.createStringFromByteArray(buffer, encoding: encoding)

    return self.createStringFromByteArray(data, encoding: encoding)
```

Comment: NSXMLParser (or any XML parser) should automatically take care of the encoding ...

Comment: Maybe would be a good idea for you to translate the error for us.

Comment: @IcaroNZ its not an error its the result that I got when I try to encode the byte array on which I removed the 0 Bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to use NSString to convert it:

```
let str = NSString(bytes: utf16, length: utf16.count, encoding: NSUTF16StringEncoding)
```

where utf16 is the string you download

Comment: I use it like that with NSString and NSUtf16StringEncoding

Comment: Where you have UInt8 did you try to use UInt16?

Comment: It looks like the CFReadStreamRead function need the uint8 array  https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFReadStreamRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFReadStreamRead

Comment: If I try to use unt16 I get an error. Can nobody help me?

Comment: Can you post your project somewhere I can look into it for you

Answer (score 0):

The xml download and encoding works. The error was on my XMLParser.
Thank you all for your help